# PHP Dropdown menu populating first fieldlist option when empty value

Tags: php

In my CMS I have an ADD NEWS MOD that populates a dropdown menu with values:

```
// Add Drop Down Menu
                elseif($thisType == "Drop Down"){

                $buffer .= '<legend>'.$thisField.'</legend>';
                $buffer .= '<select name="'.$thisField.'">';
                $buffer .= '<option value="">--- Select ---</option>';

                    for ($i=1; $i<=$thisSize; $i++ ) {

                        $thisOption = $optrow['field_option'.$i];
                        $buffer .= '<option value="'.$thisOption.'">'.$thisOption.'</option>';
                    }

                $buffer .= '</select><br /><br />';

                }
            }
```

That works perfectly for ADDING a RECORDSET. If you don't pick a value, it doesn't save anything in the database.

The challenge is, when we go back and edit the ID or Recordset, it populates the First Value of our fieldlist in our database and not the `---Select---` (empty value of the list).

Here is the edit mod function (when you edit a recordset):

```
// Edit drop down menus

                elseif($thisType == "Drop Down"){

                $buffer .= '<legend>'.$thisField.'</legend>';
                $buffer .= '<select name="'.$thisField.'">';
                // added this and SOLVED IT
                $buffer .= '<option value="">--- Select ---</option>';


                    for ($i=1; $i<=$thisSize; $i++ ) {

                        $thisOption = $optrow['field_option'.$i];

                        if($thisOption == $thisValue){
                            $checked = 'selected="yes"';
                        }   

                        $buffer .= '<option value="'.$thisOption.'" '.$checked.'>'.$thisOption.'</option>';
                        $checked = '';
                    }

                $buffer .= '</select><br /><br />';

                }
```

Doe anyone see anything obvious or what I am overlooking?

Comment: Yes, you don't actually have the default `<option>--- Select ---</option>` option in the second code block, so the first option is displayed by default.

Comment: hmm. Good catch. So maybe add another $buffer on this "edit" mod ?

Comment: Sure, no reason not to do it the same way you did in the other one.

Comment: Side note: it would be be better to initialize `$checked` _before_ checking `if($thisOption == $thisValue)`. Otherwise it will be undefined when you use it in the first iteration (unless the first option _is_ the selected option.)

Comment: What do you mean by initialize ?

Comment: I also updated the code to reflect the same output. Now it show correctly, but saves "----Select----" in the database row as the Value ??

Comment: By initialize, I mean where you set `$checked = '';` after using it in `$buffer`. You should move it up so it will be sure to be set on that first iteration.

Comment: Assigning an empty `value` attribute to your default option should prevent that other problem (`<option value="">--- Select ---</option>`). If there is no value present, the text will be used.

Comment: That was it! SOLVED, Thanks!!